# angular loop with separate arrays

Tags: angular, typescript, api, ionic3

I have these nested ng loob to print some property and use some propert to check a condition but it does not work

my Template :

```
<ion-list>
    <ng-container  *ngFor = "let publisher of publisheres " >
         <ng-container *ngFor = "let card of cards" >
            <ion-item  text-wrap  *ngFor = "let Message of card.Messages"  >

              <ion-avatar *ngIf = "Message.User_From_Id == publisher.Publisher.ID" >
                    <img src="../../assets/imgs/gonna.png" >
              </ion-avatar>

        <div *ngIf = "Message.User_From_Id == publisher.Publisher.ID"  >
            <h3> {{(card)?.Contant }} </h3>
            <h3> {{(publisher)?.Publisher.name}}   </h3>
       </div>

    </ion-item>
</ng-container>
 </ng-container>
  </ion-list>
```

my component :

```
     getPub(){
this.showLoader();

this.authService.getData().then((data) => {
  this.responseData = data;
  console.log(this.responseData);

 this.publisheres =  this.responseData 
 this.PublishersID =  this.publisheres
 this.i= this.responseData.length
 console.log(this.i);


 this.loading.dismiss();

     }, (err) => {
      console.log('error');
      this.loading.dismiss();
   });
  }

   getChats(){
       this.authService.getUnMessage().then((data) => {
       this.responseData = data;
        this.cards = this.responseData
       console.log(this.cards);
     }, (err) => {
       console.log('error');

     });


     }
```

note that cards and cards.messages are nested arrays but publishers are a separate array that  I use to make a condition

Comment: Try to print the values out in html just to check if you getting data right.

Comment: when I try print Cards only it is work fine and the same for the publishers

Comment: `this.publisheres =  this.responseData` and `this.cards = this.responseData` both pointing to same data?

Comment: I edit this but no thing change

Comment: when I check element in the browsers I got this : 
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}-->

<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->

Comment: Seems data structure isn't the way u are using in html. Better you console.log each data and post it here.

Comment: when I console.log publishers : 

(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
ID: 3
Publisher:
ID: 12
Mobile: "01278130204"
Type_Id: 1
User_Category: null
User_Description: "Marketing Company"
email: "mohamednagi1996@gmail.com"
name: "Mido"
__proto__: Object
Subscriber: null
Subscriber_ID: 96
publisher_ID: 12

Comment: when I console.log cards :
0:
Attatchments: []
Contant: "Nogghdhgsgshs"
ID: 10257
Messages: Array(1)
0:
ID: 10265
Message_Contant_ID: 10257
Recipient: null
Recivie_DateTime: "2018-10-23T05:28:56.5450045+02:00"
Seen_DateTime: null
Sender: null
User_From_Id: 12
User_To_Id: 96